# AngularJs reading data from backend to Frontend

Tags: angularjs

I'm struggling to read the below data structure in to a simple grid. any help will be greatly appreciated.

[{"Value":[],"name":Value,"name":"value","name":Value}]

Comment: What you tried so far??

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.backendAry = [{
    "Value":[],
    "name":Value,
    "name":"value",
    "name":Value
}];

//html
<table class="table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>FirstValue</th>
    <th>SecondValue</th>
    <th>ThirdValue</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="data in backendAry track by $index">
    <td>{{data.name}}</td> //put your key name instead name
    <td>{{data.name}}</td> //put your key name instead name
    <td>{{data.name}}</td> //put your key name instead name
  </tr> 
</tbody>
```